# How can I config postfix smtp to use Mailgun

Tags: centos, sendmail, mailgun, postfix-mta

I've registered in Mailgun service

But I don't find any tutorial to config postfix to use the Mailgun's smtp

tip: My server is using centos 7

Answer (score 2):

I've found these tutorials for other services but it works fine

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/setting-up-a-mail-relay/

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582187-How-to-Use-Postfix-to-Send-Email-with-Mandrill